# How to loop through a fetched page line by line with yahoo pipes

Tags: loops, yahoo-pipes

I have a Fetch Page that gives me back item like this :

A message here

```
Some text
<a rel="nofollow">http://www.somelink.com/</a>
<p>some, text, here</p>
<a rel="nofollow">text</a>
```

how can i parse this line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fetch Page** has an option called *Split by Delimiter*.
Use **\n** which is the newline character.